# URL prefill not working on website

Tags: html, url

I have an extension that embeds into Amazon called RevSeller. I'd like to pre-fill one of the fields through the URL.

My understanding is that you take the input ID of the field and put that trailing in the URL like this:

`https://www.amazon.com/dp/B01CDFU9SW?aic-ext-input-fba-buy-cost=5.53`

In this case the form ID is: **aic-ext-input-fba-buy-cost**

The value I want entered is: **5.53**

But entering that doesn't work. This is a snippet of the code from the page:

```
<
input type="number" 
min="0" 
class="aic-ext-input-buy-cost" 
id="aic-ext-input-fba-buy-cost" 
value="0"
>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What have you tried? Are you hoping for a backend or frontend solution?

Comment: I tried exactly what I put in my comment. And as this is on Amazon's website I'm assuming I can only use a front end solution? My goal is to click on the link in a Google Sheet and have it open the Amazon page with the form filled in.